# How to fetch variables with increasing numbers (to get the value of said variable) with increasing loop in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, variables, int

Say I was given values in variables and I have to add them up.

1. Can i do this by any means related to this code?

I meant to have "i" increasing and attach that increasing "i" to "num". So then I can get variable "num1" and "num2" and so on. Of course, its just a code to demonstrate what i mean(placeholder).

2. or can anyone tell me how I could get the variables into an array(if the answer lies in making an array)?

(The array should be done using the variables num1,num2... I cannot delete the variables and they should be used for the task.)

```
public class AddingStuff {

  int num1,num2,num3,num4,num5 = 10,20,30,40,50;

  public int addUpNumbers(int num1,int num2,int num3,int num4,int num5) {
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int addingtheseup = addingtheseup + ("num" + "i");
        }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method to add any amount of numbers using `varargs`:

```
public int addNumbers(int... numbers) {
     //can reference them in here as an array
     if(numbers.length == 0) return 0; //empty sum
     int sum = 0;
     for(int number: numbers) {
         sum += number;
     }
     return sum;
}
```

Your variable declaration is not correct by the way, this is the way to create multiple variables in one statement:

```
int num1 = 3, num2 = 5, num3 = 7;
```

Then you can call the method:

```
int result = addNumbers(num1,num2,num3); //you can put any integers here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get variables into an array like,

```
int[] array = {num1, num2, num3, num4, num5};
```

then you can add them altogether using,

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
}
```